# CSS Remove Parent Class On Child

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove the padding on the image, but keep the padding for the text from within the style.css file:

```
<p>
  Hello World
 <img src=""> 
</p>
```

I've set style as:

```
style.css  
p { padding: 5px 10px  }  
img { padding: 0px !important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how elements interact. Padding is space INSIDE the element and margin is space OUTSIDE the element. Both "push" an element around in the layout.

*Images don't have padding. (at least not like other elements, you would only see it if you wanted an offset border)*

Also, the text content of an element doesn't have any properties so you can't add/remove padding from that.

Your currently have something like this:

```
------------<p>-------------

some text
------------<img>-----------

------------</img>----------

------------</p>------------
```

This means the text is sitting directly on the image and there's space between the image and the bottom of the image and the end of the paragraph.

If you want space between the image and the text you would add a `margin-top` to the image to push it down. If you want to remove the space between the image and the end of the paragraph you can either remove the `padding-bottom` from the paragraph tag OR give the image a negative `margin-bottom`

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
img {
  display:block;
}

p.one {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

p.two {
  padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
  // top right bottom left
}

p.two img {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
What you have
<p class="one">
some text
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</p>

Giving the image space
<p class="two">
some text
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do; the padding will be independent for each element you specify it for; so setting `padding` for the paragraph will not apply it for the image, however setting it on the image will increase the height of the paragraph probably.

You also have the option to display them side by side without them being nested so the padding of the paragraph does not affect the image in any way at all.

```css
p {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.img2 {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.p2 {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.p3 {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Paragraph with padding and image inside with padding -->
<p>
  Hello World
  <img src="">
  <img src="" class="img2">
</p>

<!-- Paragraph without padding and image inside without padding -->
<p class="p2">
  Hello World
  <img src="">
</p>

<!-- Container with paragraph with padding and image without padding as separate elements  -->
<div class="container">
  <p class="p3">Hello World</p>
  <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: The image is wrapped in the paragraph tag so the padding appears to apply to the images as well in the OP's example

Comment: @BryceHowitson that's what I'm not sure about OP's question; if the image is inside the `p` tag, the padding of it will 'affect' it, but not exactly apply that same `padding` to the image, the image itself still has 0 padding (meaning no space between the image and the borders)

Comment: Don't really know what you are talking about, since `img` tags can definitely have `padding`

Comment: Sorry `img` content won't display padding the way text or child elements will... It actually ends up looking like margin unless you give it a border. But it doesn't work the way other box-model stuff does since the content actually has a size unlike a bunch of text

Comment: Precisely why OP's question is not fully clear as to what's the expected result

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry wasn't trying to be a jerk about it.